Is it possible to draw a histogram in ggplot from calculated values (counts for each bin and the range for each bin)?
I was wondering if it is possible to draw histograms in ggplot from values calculated elsewhere.
I have the counts for each bin and the min and max range for each bin in the analysis output from another software (EcoSim 7.1). All I want is to draw an histogram using EcoSim data output.
The following is an actual example of simulation frequencies generated by Ecosim:



Histogram Low
Histogram High
# Simulations




1.42416
1.43086
443


1.43086
1.43756
1672


1.43756
1.44426
2679


1.44426
1.45096
2263


1.45096
1.45766
1546


1.45766
1.46436
857


1.46436
1.47106
320


1.47106
1.47776
112


1.47776
1.48446
39


1.48446
1.49116
19


1.49116
1.49785
33


1.49785
1.50455
16



This is the code I tried without success:
histmin <- c(1.424,1.431,1.438,1.444,1.451,1.458,1.464,1.471,1.478,1.484,1.491,1.498)
histmax <- c(1.431,1.438,1.444,1.451,1.458,1.464,1.471,1.478,1.484,1.491,1.498,1.505)
freq <- c(443,1672,2679,2263,1546,857,320,112,39,19,33,16)
ecosimhist <- data.frame(histmin, histmax, freq)
ggplot(ecosimhist, aes(x=freq)) + geom_histogram(bins=12)


You could use geom_col(), plotting the freq variable on the y-axis and the midpoint of each range on the x.

You can calculate the center point of each bin and use geom_col like this:
library(tidyverse)

histmin <- c(1.424,1.431,1.438,1.444,1.451,1.458,1.464,1.471,1.478,1.484,1.491,1.498)
histmax <- c(1.431,1.438,1.444,1.451,1.458,1.464,1.471,1.478,1.484,1.491,1.498,1.505)
freq <- c(443,1672,2679,2263,1546,857,320,112,39,19,33,16)

ecosimhist <- data.frame(histmin, histmax, freq)


width <- histmax - histmin


ecosimhist |> 
        mutate(x = (histmin + histmax)/2) |> 
        ggplot() + 
        geom_col(aes(x = x, y = freq), 
                 width = width, color = "grey") + 
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(histmin, histmax)) + 
        theme_bw()


Created on 2024-04-27 with reprex v2.1.0

A further option showing the simulation ranges and using geom_histogram() with stat = "count":
library(tidyverse)

histmin <- c(1.424,1.431,1.438,1.444,1.451,1.458,1.464,1.471,1.478,1.484,1.491,1.498)
histmax <- c(1.431,1.438,1.444,1.451,1.458,1.464,1.471,1.478,1.484,1.491,1.498,1.505)
freq <- c(443,1672,2679,2263,1546,857,320,112,39,19,33,16)
ecosimhist <- data.frame(histmin, histmax, freq)

ecosimhist |> 
  uncount(freq) |> 
  mutate(range = paste(histmin, "-", histmax)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(range)) +
  geom_histogram(stat = "count") +
  labs(x = "Simulation Range") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))


Created on 2024-04-28 with reprex v2.1.0
